I can't connect to Wi-Fi on my RedmiBook 16 laptop with Pop OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
It connects to a cell phone hotspot without any problems. But to the router, it's a mess. It keeps trying to connect, but crashes and asks for the network password again. The WPS button doesn't help at all, but rather disables the router itself.

I tried everything, but I'm still stuck.
Here are a few commands whose output has been requested quite often:
sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0847]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

dmesg | grep ath10k
[   20.448094] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.473197] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   20.685266] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 11ad:0847
[   20.685277] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   20.685875] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00309- api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,mfp crc32 0793bcf2
[   20.753638] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 1 bmi_id N/A crc32 70c38a29
[   20.861530] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.87 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   20.950297] ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0

If anybody has encountered this before, please help me out. At the moment, I have no idea what to do

installed the driver for my Wi-Fi card Which one? And Why? Any currently supported release of Pop_OS shouldn't need any manually installed driver for any Qualcomm Atheros card Please [edit] the question to clarify and while at that please add your OS release as well.

On other forums, people kept saying that you need to install the correct driver because "pop os can't do it". So I tried to install the correct one. But it seems that this is no longer relevant

this edit isn't helpful, other than adding the OS release as requested, but removing the whole part about what you did, supposedly, is a bad practice. On other forums, people kept saying that you need to install the correct driver because "pop os can't do it" is ONLY applicable to devices that work with proprietary drivers, NOT the case here. You may have inadvertently make it worse. Now, what about the router? How old is it? What bands it supports? What encryption settings? Keep in mind ONLY WPA2-AES or newer is recommend.

The router is 1 year old. It supports 2.4G and 5G bands. WPA-WPA2 encryption

Mixed WPA-WPA2 could be the problem. Again, change it to WPA2-AES or newer WPA3 if available. That should all.

I change it to WPA3. Everything stays the same

Keep it anyway, security is important and you shouldn't use encryption methods from 20 years ago. Now, in order to troubleshoot, I suggest you run a live session, preferably with the current release - 24.04 - and try to connect to the WiFi. If it works, the problem is with your current installation.
